# How does one know which versions of which packages go together in a LAMP Stack in Ubuntu?

Tags: apt, package-management, apache2, mysql, lamp

I'm trying to install a specific version of MySQL to match a host and I'd like to install the corresponding working versions of some other packages for PHP and Apache2.

I know you can check the versions of packages available with

```
sudo apt-cache madison <package-name>
```

But how do you know that more than one package will work with the other packages?

Comment: Try the release notes for LAMP...something like this('https://confluence.cornell.edu/display/hosting/LAMP+Release+Notes') should be helpful.